# Custom date field in woocommerce only years?

Tags: date, woocommerce, custom-fields

I have created a custom field in woocommerce where i want shopowners choose a year of publishing (books in this case).
So far i have:

```
//Custom Product Date Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input(
    array(
        'id' => '_custom_product_date_field',
        'placeholder' => 'Publicatiedatum',
        'label' => __('Publicatiedatum:', 'woocommerce'),
        'type' => 'date',
        'date-type' => 'years'
        )
    );
```

How can i set the date-type to years, as the last key => value (date-type:years) is not working?

Comment: Why using a date picker to pick a year only? That is not logical… There is other simpler alternatives.

Comment: Because the user has to select a date to publish. I am wondering what does wp_text_input accept as possible arguments? I cannot find a good reference...

Comment: I didn't even know that this complex date picker was possible to be enabled in `woocommerce_wp_text_input()` function. I have searched in the source code of Woocommerce, but I didn't find anything useful related, to make possible this kind of customizations. I have always used other ways to get a jquery-ui datepicker, which allow a lot of customizations as you are asking in this question (but it needs much more coding and testing).

Comment: You are right that it can be simpler. I used type=>number and added a minimum number starting from 2010 and then steps of 1. However, i am still curious wether one can change the date picker layout by passing arguments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious since I was looking for details on using the date field in a woocommerce custom field. I didn't need year only specifically but it was an interesting rabbit hole to run down.

Trying to understand a bit more how `woocommerce_wp_text_input` creates these fields it started to become more apparent that supplying the `type` attribute simply passes it on to the HTML attributes. That said, these are standard HTML elements, not a wrapper of sorts that produces more fancy fields utilizing things like jQuery which seems like what the OP was expecting.

Looking over the [specs for the date-related HTML text input fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats) it becomes apparent that there is not an `<input>` of `type="year"` available in the spec. We are limited to the `type`'s specified in the specs.

I was able to successfully create a `month` input with the following:

```
      woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        [
          'id' => '_my_month',
          'label' => __('My month', 'woocommerce'),
          'value' => get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_month', true),
          'type' => 'month',
          'custom_attributes' => [
            'min' => '2020-01',
          ],
        ]
      );
```

So understandably, from what I can see, doing what you are asking isn't possible unless the HTML specifications add a `year` input or woocommerce provides a bandaid when specifying `type` as `year`. Hopefully this better explains how `woocommerce_wp_text_input` expects the data to be formatted and what is really supported.

As an aside that might assist in completing the requirements of the original question through alternate means, you could attempt to implement a [jQuery UI picker which supports year only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40661712/178857). I however feel that the jQuery UI picker using year only is a bit clumsy being it provides a popup to simply choose a date from a dropdown AND the left/right pagination of the popup still pages through months while showing only years. You might as well just use a dropdown or a number field with the date min/max values you require, both have example code that can be seen in other answers on that aforementioned answer I linked.

Comment: This was a long time ago, but thanks for posting!