# How to get selected date into the text box from the calendar-that popup from Icon?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am designing a project in Asp.net-MVC 5 with C#. I am having a textbox along with a calendar Icon attached at the end. 
codings below:

**Design:**

```
<div class="col-md-4  col-lg-4">
   <label>From</label>
   <div class="input-group date">
      <input type="text" name="q" id="txtFrom" class="form-control" >
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" name="search" id="datepicker" class="btn btn-flat btn-success">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </button>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
        $(function () { 
          $('#txtFrom').datepicker({
           autoclose: true
       })       
   })
</script>
```

This one is working fine, like when I click the text box, the calendar pops up and the selected date was shown in 'From' text box.

***But, What I need is-the calendar must pop up only if the calendar Icon got clicked and the selected date must be displayed in 'From' Text box.***

If I changed the script as below

Script:

```
 <script>
        $(function () { 
          $('#datepicker').datepicker({
           autoclose: true
       })       
   })
</script>
```

then the Pop up comes when Calendar Icon got clicked, but the value not sent to the text box.
Image of my TextBox Design :

[image: Image of my TextBox Design]

Kindly Help. TIA.

Comment: Why you create your own datepicker, there is one from HTML:
  `<input type="date" name="yourdate">`

Comment: oh If I use `type="date"` means, I no need to call my datepicker ah?

Comment: It will be much more better, if the calendar pop out by clicking Icon and the selected date will be shown in text box..

Comment: @Presi One more doubt, my few text boxes need to choose year only. How to give years only calendar?

Comment: Watch my Answer, I put some examples. Take the second, looks nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use html5 tag

```
<input type="date">
```

Comment: If I add your code, I no need to use my Icon and date picker right??

Comment: How to display current date in the text box as a sample

Comment: you can write this ```<input type="date" value="2019-07-18">```

Comment: but the value must be current date.. IF I open tommorrow it will shows as today's date right?

Comment: One more doubt, my few text boxes need to choose year only. How to give years only calendar?

Comment: passing current date isnt possible in pure html, but you can try JS or PHP, here's the example: [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/html-input-date-field-how-to-set-default-value-to-todays-date)

Comment: i think if you need to pass year only, then u can use simple text input and validate it to use only year format, as a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If you want to choose year only, like you asked in your comment, see this:

[Can I use an HTML input type "date" to collect only a year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676752/can-i-use-an-html-input-type-date-to-collect-only-a-year)

Or this (even nicer):

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/ucfxywh6/`
```

Comment: Fiddle one is what I am looking for.. But I tried ur both answers but it is not working for me.. I dont know Y.. I used the same code...

Comment: What's the problem? Not showing or what is happening

Comment: I used the code.. while clicking testbox- there is no change.. I used the same code from fiddle that u gave, but calendar year pop up never come out.. which means the function in script is not working ah??

Comment: I think you forgot to add the javascript libraries. In the fiddle are the ressources. You need them to execute the code