# How to display an input with type="date" with date format yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: html, date, input, format

```
<input type="date" name="date" autoComplete="on" value={this.state.value} />
```

> and this one displays date format dd/mm/yyyy
> and I want to display the date format like this: yyyy-mm-dd

> I really appreciate your help.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676752/can-i-use-an-html-input-type-date-to-collect-only-a-year

Answer (score -1):

You can use inputmask plugin.

[Look this](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)