# How to get datepicker to show only years on datatables date filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

By using datatables, I am trying to get my two date pickers to let the user only select years, not months or days.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to work properly:

```js
var minDate, maxDate;

    // Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = minDate.val();
            var max = maxDate.val();
            var date = new Date(data[13]);

            if (
                (min === null && max === null) ||
                (min === null && date <= max) ||
                (min <= date && max === null) ||
                (min <= date && date <= max)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );

    $(document).ready(function () {
        minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
            format: 'YYYY'
        });
        maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
            format: 'YYYY'
        });

        $.noConflict();

        var table = $('.table').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            autoWidth: false,
            ordering: false
        });

        $('#filterDates').on('click', function () {
            table.draw();
        });
    });
```

Here are my datepickers:

```html
<div>
From: <input type="text" class="form-horizontal" id="min" name="min" />
&nbsp;To: <input type="text" class="form-horizontal" id="max" name="max" />
&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" id="filterDates">Filter Dates</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That sounds like a HTML question about `<input type="date" ...>` and maybe not a DataTables question. What datepicker are you actually using?

Comment: Take a look at [Can I use an HTML input type "date" to collect only a year?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34676752/12567365) - maybe you just need a 4-digit integer, not a date picker?

Comment: I'm using DateTime datepickers from Datatables, one of them as an id of "min", and the other "max".

Comment: Can you show us the code for them in your question?

Comment: (To be clear, I am talking about the date pickers where the users enter their data. The HTML.)

Comment: Thank you. So, you are not actually using any date pickers. You are using text input fields. You can use the question I linked to, above, to display only year values. Then you don't need to use `DateTime` in your  JavaScript. You just need to extract the year portion of your table's date values, for the comparison logic.

Comment: So my `minDate` and `maxDate` should be integers?

Comment: This is what your question is asking for: "_to only show years_" and  "_to let the user only select years_". It doesn't matter whether the year is then handled as a string or an integer in JavaScript. You can compare two strings **each containing exactly 4 digits** in the same way as you can compare two integers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247034/discussion-between-young-a-and-andrewjames).

Comment: Actually, I got it now, thank you so much !

Comment: Nice! You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I need number inputs fields instead of date pickers.

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = parseInt($('#min').val());
            var max = parseInt($('#max').val());
            var date = parseInt(data[13]) || 0;

            if (
                (isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
                (isNaN(min) && date <= max) ||
                (min <= date && isNaN(max)) ||
                (min <= date && date <= max)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.noConflict();

        var table = $('.table').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            autoWidth: false,
            ordering: false
        });

        $('#min, #max').on('click', function () {
            table.draw();
        });
    });
```